# Bind TextBlock text when it is more then a simple string

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a textblock and I would like to bind its content to a property in my viewmodel. This is fine if the content is a simple string. But it's no so fine if I want to format the content and use  or  tags... In this case I cannot bind a string: the textblock would simply display a string like this "Hallo".

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Actually the editor deleted some part of my question and I think this made it not clear. I wanted to know if it possible to bind a FlowDocument to a texblock , rather then a simple string. The Texblock can display Run tags by using the Inlines property. Is there a way to bind to this ?

Comment: You could have asked this in your question. The sole edited part is the question title. You might have tried to bind to the `Inlines` property and seen that it won't work since it is readonly. You might also consider to use a RichTextBox and bind to its [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a property of some type - you can create a datatemplate for this type

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MySomeType}">
  <!--your visual presentation goes here-->
</DataTemplate>
```

now you can simply use a ContentPresenter to show your property

```
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MySomeTypeProperty}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

See what the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property can do for you. If that is not sufficient, you might want to write a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  <Textblock content="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat={}Hello {1}}" />
```

Just got to play with the string format.

Comment: You certainly mean `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat=Hello {0}}"/>`. Note the CamelCase in `TextBlock`, the property `Text` instead of `content`, the superfluous {} in `StringFormat`, and the parameter index `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Yea thx for that clear up. I've used string format in xaml only few times.